# A Vector of acute angle to all vectors in a set

Tags: linear-algebra

I´m interested in the following problem:

Given a set $A$ of vectors in $R^n$, find out whether it is possible to find a vector $v$ s.t. $$\forall a \in A: v\cdot a \gt 0,$$
or in other words, the angle between $v$ and every vector in $A$ is acute (and if it is possible, find one).

Obviously, this can be formulated as a linear programming, but I hope that there are more specific tools. Does anybody know if this problem has been researched and whether good algorithms exist for this purpose?

Comment: This seems like it's related to the study of [convex cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone) and, in particular, [Dual cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone).

Comment: Is $A$ a finite list of vectors?  Is it a closed set?

Comment: In my case it is a finite set, but anyway you can take all affine combinations of vectors from $A$ and replace $A$ with them and it would be equivalent, so it does not matter much I think..

Comment: In that case, you're considering [finitely generated cones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone#Polyhedral_and_finitely_generated_cones).

Comment: My gut says that it is equivalent to determine that $a_1 \cdot a_2 > 0$ for every pair of vectors in $A$.

Comment: No, for $A = \{(-1, 1), (1,0)\}$ you have $v=(1, 2)$ as a counter-example.

Comment: @lolpop you're right, that should have been more obvious.  Anyway, that's all I have.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is equivalent to asking whether the [dual cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_cone_and_polar_cone) of $A$ has a non-empty [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_(topology)), which is to say that its linear combinations span all of $\Bbb R^n$.  The general area you should be looking into is [convex optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization). I hope that helps you find some leads.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to see if $A$ can be rotated about the origin to end up contained in one of the orthants (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant) of the space.

Comment: In general, it suffices to see if $A$ can be contained in a convex cone that is also a proper subset of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I think I understand you correctly - and it won't work, as the angle between two vectors in $A$ may be greater than 90 degrees.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, how would you do that?

Comment: @lolopop actually, that is not even correct. For example, if $A = \{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0)\}$, my proposition fails.

Comment: this is a strict inequality, so no v for this example..